# How to take a normal 2D photo on Google Cardboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm a VR developer trying to make an app on Google Cardboard that can do something after it takes a 2D normal photo(Simple-nonVR photo that we take using any camera). Basically, I want to view the real world using camera on Google Cardboard, and take a photo of what I see. Apparently, Google Cardboard Camera app takes a VR photo, not a normal photo.

Any suggestion how this can be done on Unity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.CaptureScreenshot`?

Comment: I haven't but I will. Thank you for the suggestion